# How to cv2.imread from a url with basic authentication

Tags: python, qr-code, opencv

I am trying to use cv2 and pyzbar for real time reading of QR codes from an IP camera.

This works:

```
os.system("wget --quiet http://user:password@url -O file.jpg")
image = cv2.imread("file.jpg")
barcodes = pyzbar.decode(image)
```

But it's clearly inefficient - much better to imread the url directly. But I can't work out how to do that with basic authentication. Would really appreciate some help.

(There have been a number of similar questions but I can't find any that have been answered!)

thanks

Dan

Comment: maybe this might be a hint: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169398/python-video-streaming-server-and-client

Comment: thanks, and I can see the solution is in there, but it's too complicated/uncommented for my basic python skills to understand quite what he's doing.

Answer (score 2):

or there's this alternative simple solution that doesn't involve streaming the video:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import numpy as np

resp = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))

image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.content), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Hope it helps other people!

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

```
import numpy as np
import urllib.request as rq
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# load image from url
def urlToImage(url):
    # download image,convert to a NumPy array,and read it into opencv
    resp = rq.urlopen(url)
    img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()),dtype="uint8")
    img = cv2.imdecode(img,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    #return the image
    return img
img = urlToImage("https://www.pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/google_logo.png")
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: thanks, but that approach doesn't work with basic authentication - I get an "http.client.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port:" error

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all - but turns out there is a nice simple answer:

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture("http://user:password@url")
_, image=cap.read()
barcodes = pyzbar.decode(image)
```